# Android Preference - set custom background?

Tags: android, background, preference

I have a small problem. I would like to enable/disable some Preferences in my app depending on TRIAL/PRO version of my app.

and when I disable some Preference and it is grayed, I would like to add some icon or resource to it to notify the user that this is PRO function.

For example I want to look my preference like this (very simple ugly example, but I did it in 30 seconds):

[image]

How to do something like this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a theme:

In you manifest:

```
    <!-- Let Preferences have their own theme -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.ACTIVITY_Prefs"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.APP.Prefs"
    />
```

You then have to create that theme called APP.Prefs

**[EDIT]**

To give preferences their own layout:

In your res/layout folder, put a new layout (feel free to do modifications).
I called mine **prefs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+android:id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/displayTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
            android:shadowColor="@color/white"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="1"
            android:maxLines="4"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that I'm using my own colors defined in **res/values/colors.xml**

Now, in your preference file (mine is res/xml/prefs.xml):

Every preference you want to customize must have that layout assigned
(or some other, if say, you want different colors per each preference type or 
so)

```
        android:layout="@layout/prefs"
```

If you want to change the widget icon (or to assign a missing one):

```
        android:widgetLayout="@layout/arr_dn"
```

(It's a layout which contains a drawable)

Comment: ok, and how to I create another icon on right? Extending some theme doesn't solve my problem, all I can do with your solution is to change text color or sizes in my opinion...

Comment: So, you have to give preferences their own layout. I'm going to extend my answer to show you how I do that

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but I do not quite udnerstand...I know now how to change layout of preference to custom (using android:layout) but how to add the icon on right? Also I do not understand what do you mean under "If you want to change the widget icon"

Comment: Exactly what you want to do: CHANGE the icon on the right (which is called... "**widget layout**").

Comment: still do not understand...EDIT: I will try to play with this a while...thanks for now

Comment: In your case, you can make a TextView called **res/layout/pro.xml** with a yellow background color and a black text and the text saying "PRO". Then refer this layout in your Preference: **android:widgetLayout="@layout/pro"**

Comment: this is exactly what I did few minutes ago and it works :)) Actually docs is again a little misleading, as it doesn't describe very good the difference between layout and widgetLayout. But it doesn;t matter now...There is only the last question - how to set it visible/invisible in code?

Comment: Ok problem resolved - I just created simple layout where is only 1 ImageView with some icon. Then I set to my preference "android:widgetLayout=myCustomLayout" and in code I just checked if this is PRO version or TRIAL and if PRO I disabled this widgetLayoutlike this: findPreference(getString(R.string.prefTransparency)).setWidgetLayoutResource(0); and that's all :)

Comment: but you helped me a lot, though I realized few things independently. I will mark your answer as helpful :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can have a custom layout for list items, with text and image (as you have shown) , and based on the version(trial or pro) of the app, toggle the visibility of the image.

Here is an example to create a custom list view

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: I know how I can create custom view for anything, but how to create custom view for preference? Because I really do not know for example default preferences paddings, margins, text sizes, text colors, etc...And just trying to find them isn't very good solution for me, as it can be different on different devices.

Comment: i dont understand, do you have a preference screen for your app, which shows the preferences available in your app ?

Comment: it is impossible to create custom layout for something if you do not have color values, text sizes, padding and margins...That's all. I do not have this values, and do not know how to get them (from where?) - because I need to have my custom layout look EXACTLY same like default preference layout and the only difference should be 1 icon on right

Comment: you should metion in your question that you want EXACTLY same layout as the default layout + image.